# Authentication error Airflow 1.9.0 Trying to LogIn -- Invalid salt

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow, bcrypt

I have am running Airflow 1.9.0 in EC2 instance with a Database in RDS (posgreSQL).

I am using authentication in airflow and I am trying to create a new user with the following steps:

```
    >>> import airflow
    >>> from airflow import models, settings
    >>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
    >>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
    >>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
    >>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
    >>>  user._set_password = 'mypassword'  
    >>> session = settings.Session()
    >>> session.add(user)
    >>> session.commit()
    >>> session.close()
    >>> exit()
```

When I try to execute session.commit() I have an error like this

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
context)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 943, in commit
self.transaction.commit()
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 467, in commit
self._prepare_impl()
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 447, in _prepare_impl
self.session.flush()
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2254, in flush
self._flush(objects)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2381, in _flush
transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 249, in reraise
raise value
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2345, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 395, in execute
rec.execute(self)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 560, in execute
uow
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
mapper, table, insert)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 866, in _emit_insert_statements
execute(statement, params)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
context)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
exc_info
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 248, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
context)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users         [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('[![czambrano', 'some@email.com', b'$2b$12$1r4vhFaJHJEvOssY/EuDMuPQtN26M2crNHRjFowxYSf189P9HRkju'][1]][1])] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I checked my RDS instance and the table users is created in this way

[image]

So I tried insert in to table manually the values that I receive before: czambrano', 'some@email.com', b'$2b$12$1r4vhFaJHJEvOssY/EuDMuPQtN26M2crNHRjFowxYSf189P9HRkju'

But when I tried to log in into Airflow I get an error:

```
                     ____/ (  (    )   )  \___
                     /( (  (  )   _    ))  )   )\
                   ((     (   )(    )  )   (   )  )
                 ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
               ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
              (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
              ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
             ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
              (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
             ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
              ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
               (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
               ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                        (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                      (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                       (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                     (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                      (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                    (        |(||(||)||||        )
                      (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                    (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Node: ip-10-7-0-242.ec2.internal
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 645, in login
return airflow.login.login(self, request)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py", line 135, in login
if not user.authenticate(password):
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py", line 66, in authenticate
return check_password_hash(self._password, plaintext)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 67, in check_password_hash
return Bcrypt().check_password_hash(pw_hash, password)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 193, in check_password_hash
return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/pampita-jFcteNag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 87, in hashpw
      ValueError: Invalid salt
```

Some Help would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Run `upgradedb` so that it would create necessary table or add necessary columns.

Also then run the following: (**Note** `.encode('utf-8')`)

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'new_user'
user.email = 'newuser@example.com'
user._set_password = 'mypassword'.encode('utf8')
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

This should resolve it.